# UILabel update issue for newly clicked cells in TableView - first clicked cell title is retained

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I'm fairly new to iOS development, but have yet to find a fix for this after extensive searching.

The issue is that when a table cell is clicked, it's title information (built from an array at index) is sent to a UILabel on the Detail view controller. **Then** after clicking back to the MasterViewController TableViewCells, and selecting a different cell, it's title is not passed to the UILabel, and the previously or first item clicked information is retained.

This may be a release/retain issue, or a table reloadData issue but no matter where I try to add these in for my objects or table it won't reset the "currentNodeTitle" on DetailViewController to be the newly clicked cell before sending it to the UILabel.

Here is my setup:

I have a table with cells created from an NSMutableArray called nodeTitles.

The NSLog output of the array data is 
nodeTitles: (
    Issue,
    "Issue 2",
    "Issue 3",
    "Issue 4",
    "Issue 5",
    "Issue 6",
    "Issue 7"
)

**In MasterViewController.h:**

```
@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray * nodeTitles;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nodeTitles;    
@end
```

**In MasterViewController.m:**

From the array each cell is created with the contents of each indexed row.

```
nodeTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Issue", @"Issue 2",@"Issue 3", @"Issue 4", @"Issue 5", @"Issue 6", @"Issue 7", nil];
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath) {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}

//*only thing added*
cell.textLabel.text = [self.nodeTitles objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
//*end only thing added*

return cell;}
```

Then for the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (!self.detailViewController) {
            self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        self.detailViewController.currentNodeTitle = [nodeTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[contentTitleArray release];

    }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Everything is working at this point. I've got a list of table view cells, with the content from my array and when clicked, I've linked these to a UILabel.

My Dealloc, viewDidUnload, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewWillDissappear in MasterViewController:

```
- (void)dealloc
    {
      [self.nodeTitles release];
      [_detailViewController release];
      [super dealloc];
    }
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.nodeTitles = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**My DetailViewController.h:**

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeTitle;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableString *currentNodeTitle;

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**:

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;
@synthesize masterPopoverController = _masterPopoverController;
@synthesize currentNodeTitle;

- (void)dealloc
{
    currentNodeTitle = nil;
    [_detailItem release];
    [_detailDescriptionLabel release];
    [_masterPopoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

In the viewDidLoad on **DetailViewController.m**, I'm setting the UILabel item with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = currentNodeTitle;
    _detailDescriptionLabel.text = currentNodeTitle;

    [self configureView];    
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
   [currentNodeTitle release];
}
```

After clicking on an item, and the clicking back to the master controller, how can I get a newly selected cell title to show in the UILabel on the DetailViewController?

thanks~

Comment: Specify your question and tell me what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController.currentNodeTitle = [nodeTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I think this IF statement is not executed again since detailViewController is valid.
Move the currentNodeTitle assignment out of the IF block.

**EDIT**
You are retaining the detailViewController, so it looks like viewDidLoad is being called only once and that is the only place where you use the currentNodeTitle.

Try moving the

```
self.title = currentNodeTitle;
_detailDescriptionLabel.text = currentNodeTitle;
```

to viewWillAppear: since it will be called every time you push the detailViewController.

Comment: I've made this change with no success. Re-selecting cells (after an initial cell is selected) still uses the UILabel title info from the first cell clicked. - any other ideas? I think it must be a release or retain issue somewhere.

Comment: This worked, big huge thanks! If I had more rep points I would +50 you!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are making your new label then just reload the table. One think also you should follow that, make a label in the `if(cell == nil) { [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; }` then make tag of this label then after this condition review the label `label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:labeltag]`

may be then it will help your problem.

Comment: Emon, I had trouble understanding your solution. I did already get this working though by adding my DetailViewController.m code that sets the detailLabelItem within - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated. Nonetheless, thanks for your reply